# How to call WCF Rest service with Basic Auth using Postman?

Tags: wcf, postman, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I have created a WCF service with Basic Authentication following this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-basic-authentication.
But when I call it using Postman, I get an error (400 Bad Request).

If I use a small application written in C# setting out ClientCredentials, it works well.

Here is my server code:

```
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public bool GetData()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "GetData")]
    bool GetData();
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="UsernameWithTransport">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="BasicAuthenticationTest">
                <endpoint 
                    address=""
                    binding="wsHttpBinding"   
                    bindingConfiguration="UsernameWithTransport"  
                    name="BasicEndpoint"  
                    contract="BasicAuthTest.IDataService"/>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[image]

I also turned off "SSL certificate verification" and proxy in Postman

Comment: error in detail please!

Comment: empty body with Status 400

Comment: Can't say wants wrong from the code shown in the question, could you create a sample code with issue and send me public repo. link?